# Node.js suddenly getting extremely slow

Tags: performance, node.js

We have this architecture with 2 node processes.

One polls a private API and pushes the changes to the second node if any.
The second node process the data and calls a bunch other API's and eventually emits a change event to the client, a HTML5 website, with socket.io

This second node will always process the data and will always emit changes even if no clients are connected. So in my opinion the CPU or mem usage is not that greatly affected by the number of connected clients. Also note that this architecture is still running on a private staging environment.

Everything runs fine and we're ready to go live until we noticed after couple of days, maybe a week, the second node suddenly gets extremely slow while the first node is still fine.

It gets so bad that even the connection between the two nodes gets timed out and they are on the same network over localhost. It also takes more then 10 seconds to browse to the socket.io/socket.io.js file.

I know its very hard to understand the problem without seeing any code but I'm kinda pulling my hair out because we have to go live in couple of days and my logs are not revealing anything and google isn't helping either.

**Whats a good practice towards building Have you ever experienced anything like this? What was the problem and how did you fix it?**

**Whats a good monitor and profiler for node.js? (preferably free)**

**What are good practices towards building a node.js app with makes a lot of outgoing API calls?**

Anything or anyone that could help me in the right direction of solving or even discovering the actual problem will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Never experienced anything like this but may be the second node is blocking the event loop by doing CPU intensive work or waiting for some resource synchronously.

Add some logging in your code to see how much time second node is taking for processing each change pushed by first node. May be some type of change consumes CPU for 10 seconds or so to complete.

You should also start monitoring memory, CPU and network connections. When things slow down your monitoring will provide some clue as to where is the bottle neck.

For monitoring you can try following 3 tools

1. [nodetime](http://nodetime.com/)
2. [hummingbird](http://projects.nuttnet.net/hummingbird/)
3. [node-monitor](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-monitor)

Also read http://nodetime.com/blog/monitoring-nodejs-application-performance

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a memory leak somewhere in the second node, maybe from calling too many anonymous functions etc... do you notice your RAM usage slightly creeping up as it runs?

Comment: Yes I do write a lot of anonymous inline callbacks, I thought that was the way to node? I restarted the app 4hrs ago and it hasn't increased in CPU or mem usage, the starting up is the most intensive moment because it has to catch up with a lot of data and has to make a lot of API calls, but it's still running smooth for now.

Comment: It really depends on the GC implementation but calling anonymous functions in any GC language is probably the leading cause of memory leaks.  This is because there is no reference to that object to begin with so it prevents the GC from easily cleaning it up when there are no more references to that object.  I am not sure if this is the cause of your problem though as I can't see your code : )

Comment: Really? Schooled. Thanks.